# Convert a character to an integer in C++ language

Tags: c++

I want to convert from `char` to `integer`,
following is the code-

```
FILE *p;
char temp;
int temp_int;
p=fopen("week3data","r");    
temp=getc(p);
temp_int=atoi(temp)
```

number in file goes from `1 to 200`, need some guidance.

Comment: Convert a single digit *character*, or convert a *string* containing a full three-digit number?

Comment: What is the question exactly? Also pretty sure this is a duplicate...

Comment: And are you sure you're programing in C++ and not C? There's no explicit C++ functionality in the code you show, only old C.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using C++, please use C++ SL:

```
std::fstream stream("file.txt", std::ios_base::in);
float number;
stream >> number;
std::cout << number;
```

Edit: Don't forget to check if your stream is valid:

```
if (!stream) {
  throw std::runtime_error("Cannot open file");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're reading from a file, you shouldnt be using

```
temp=getc(p);
```

and if you use

```
temp=fgetc(p);
```

and the number is, for example 200, you will only read the "2".

so the answer is:

better use

```
char * buffer; 
fgets(buffer,10, p);
temp_int=atoi(buffer);
```

Comment: bufffer, not temp. Also what if the number is 10000000001? :)

Comment: That `buffer` looks a bit too uninitialized to be honest.

Comment: Actually buffer size 10 will do... Sorry

Comment: @Akalikin thanks for showing the mistake, it was buffer not temp. He said the numer goes between 1 and 200... so obviously with buffer size 10 its far enough... but what if number is 1000000000000? well this would be out of his problem.

Comment: @Quentin : im not giving him the whole code of course, i just gave him what he needed to reach the answer.

Comment: That's a valid reason. I'd put a *insert proper initialization here* comment though (you'de be surprised).